# php pear: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted

Tags: ubuntu, php, pear

I'm really in deep sh*t here. While running "pear install HTTP", my server get rebooted, when everything back, I continue my work, and...

```
$sudo pear install HTTP
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.

$sudo pear list
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.

$sudo pear 
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.
```

I try aptitude purge php-pear, and even delete everything on  /usr/share/php/ and install php-pear again, but the error still persist.

Oops... what did happen?

Answer (score 3):

Had this error on Mac with MAMP. For me deleting .../MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf helped.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting .pearrc on the home directories shall fix this problems. --Thanks God.